# How to do pandas groupby([multiple columns]) so its result can be looked up

Tags: group-by, pandas, multiple-columns, statistics

I have two dataframes: `tr` is a training-set, `ts` is a test-set.
They contain columns `uid` (a user_id), `categ` (a categorical), and `response`.
`response` is the dependent variable I'm trying to predict in ts.

I am trying to compute the mean of `response` in `tr`, broken out by columns `uid` and `categ`:

```
avg_response_uid_categ = tr.groupby(['uid','categ']).response.mean()
```

This gives the result but (unwantedly) the dataframe index is a MultiIndex. (this is the `groupby(..., as_index=True)` behavior):

```
MultiIndex[--5hzxWLz5ozIg6OMo6tpQ  SomeValueOfCateg, --65q1FpAL_UQtVZ2PTGew  AnotherValueofCateg, ...
```

But instead I want the result to keep the two columns 'uid', 'categ' and keep them separate.

Should I use `aggregate()` instead of `groupby()`?
Trying `groupby(as_index=False)` is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result seems to differ depending on whether you do:

```
tr.groupby(['uid','categ']).response.mean()
```

or:

```
tr.groupby(['uid','categ'])['response'].mean()  # RIGHT
```

i.e. whether you slice a single Series, or a DataFrame containing a single Series. Related: [Pandas selecting by label sometimes return Series, sometimes returns DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383647/pandas-selecting-by-label-sometimes-return-series-sometimes-returns-dataframe)