# Pandas selecting by label sometimes return Series, sometimes returns DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, series

In Pandas, when I select a label that only has one entry in the index I get back a Series, but when I select an entry that has more then one entry I get back a data frame.

Why is that?  Is there a way to ensure I always get back a data frame?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=range(5), index=[1, 2, 3, 3, 3])

In [3]: type(df.loc[3])
Out[3]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [4]: type(df.loc[1])
Out[4]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Granted that the behavior is inconsistent, but I think it's easy to imagine cases where this is convenient. Anyway, to get a DataFrame every time, just pass a list to `loc`. There are other ways, but in my opinion this is the cleanest.

```
In [2]: type(df.loc[[3]])
Out[2]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [3]: type(df.loc[[1]])
Out[3]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Comment: Indeed, this is cleaner than my options :-)

Comment: Thanks.
Worth noting that this returns a DataFrame even if the label isn't in the index.

Comment: FYI, with a non-duplicate index, and a single indexer (e.g. a single label), you will ALWAYS get back a Series, its only because you have duplicates in the index that it is a DataFrame.

Comment: Note that there is a yet another gotcha: if using the suggested workaround, and there are no matching rows, the result will be a DataFrame with a single row, all NaN.

Comment: Paul, what version of pandas are you using? On the latest version, I get a `KeyError` when I try `.loc[[nonexistent_label]]`.

Comment: If you are selecting both on the index and the columns then the loc requires 2 lists to get a dataframe rather than a series: df.loc[ [indexlist], [columnlist] ] (even if the list contains just a single item).

Comment: very useful observation @Jeff . adding to it, the index also needs to be sorted.

Comment: Using a list in `.loc` is much slower than without it.  To be still readable but also much faster, better use `df.loc[1:1]`

Comment: In my opinion this answer is misleading. Both `df['column']` and `df.loc[:, 'column']` will return a Series. Both `df[['column']]` and `df.loc[:, ['column']]` will return a DataFrame. The difference lies not in `loc`, but in whether you are using a string (`'column'`) or a list (`['column']`) to index. So the anser is really: string --> Series, list --> DataFrame. `loc` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 32):

## The TLDR

### When using `loc`

`df.loc[:]` = **Dataframe**

`df.loc[int]` = **Dataframe** if you have more than one column and **Series** if you have only 1 column in the dataframe

`df.loc[:, ["col_name"]]` = **Dataframe** if you have more than one row and **Series** if you have only 1 row in the selection

`df.loc[:, "col_name"]` = **Series**

### Not using `loc`

`df["col_name"]` = **Series**

`df[["col_name"]]` = **Dataframe**

Comment: This is incorrect. `df.loc[:, ["col_name"]]` would return a series if only one row is selected.

Comment: right, if the dataframe consisted of just a single row, since the `:` selects all rows

Comment: so since one is concerned with the type of the results, perhaps you could add different sections specifying that the type is different depending on the cardinality of the results.

Comment: `df.loc[int]` returns a series, unless rows of `df` are not indexed with unique integers.  (Not sure if this is version dependent behavior.)

Answer (score 20):

You have an index with three index items `3`. For this reason `df.loc[3]` will return a dataframe.

The reason is that you don't specify the column. So `df.loc[3]` selects three items of all columns (which is column `0`), while `df.loc[3,0]` will return a Series. E.g. `df.loc[1:2]` also returns a dataframe, because you slice the rows.

Selecting a single row (as `df.loc[1]`) returns a Series with the column names as the index.

If you want to be sure to always have a DataFrame, you can slice like `df.loc[1:1]`. Another option is boolean indexing (`df.loc[df.index==1]`) or the take method (`df.take([0])`, but this used location not labels!).

Comment: Thats the behavior I would expect.  I don't understand the design decision for single rows to get converted into a series - why not a data frame with one row?

Comment: Ah, why selecting a single row returns a Series, I don't really know.

Comment: `df.loc[1:1]` is faster than `df.loc[[1]]`

Answer (score 8):

Use `df['columnName']` to get a Series and `df[['columnName']]` to get a Dataframe.

Comment: Beware that takes a copy of the original df.

Answer (score 5):

You wrote in a comment to joris' answer:

> "I don't understand the design
>   decision for single rows to **get converted** into a series - why not a
>   data frame with one row?"

A single row isn't **converted** in a Series.
It **IS** a Series: `No, I don't think so, in fact; see the edit`

> The best way to think about the pandas data structures is as flexible
>   containers for lower dimensional data. For example, DataFrame is a
>   container for Series, and Panel is a container for DataFrame objects.
>   We would like to be able to insert and remove objects from these
>   containers in a dictionary-like fashion.
>
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/overview.html#why-more-than-1-data-structure

The data model of Pandas objects has been choosen like that. The reason certainly lies in the fact that it ensures some advantages I don't know (I don't fully understand the last sentence of the citation, maybe it's the reason)

.

### Edit : I don't agree with me

A DataFrame can't be composed of elements that would **be** Series, because the following code gives the same type "Series" as well for a row as for a column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[11,12,13], index=[2, 3, 3])

print '-------- df -------------'
print df

print '\n------- df.loc[2] --------'
print df.loc[2]
print 'type(df.loc[1]) : ',type(df.loc[2])

print '\n--------- df[0] ----------'
print df[0]
print 'type(df[0]) : ',type(df[0])
```

result

```
-------- df -------------
    0
2  11
3  12
3  13

------- df.loc[2] --------
0    11
Name: 2, dtype: int64
type(df.loc[1]) :  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

--------- df[0] ----------
2    11
3    12
3    13
Name: 0, dtype: int64
type(df[0]) :  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

So, there is no sense to pretend that a DataFrame is composed of Series because what would these said Series be supposed to be : columns or rows ? Stupid question and vision.

.

Then what is a DataFrame ?

In the previous version of this answer, I asked this question, trying to find the answer to the `Why is that?` part of the question of the OP and the similar interrogation `single rows to get converted into a series - why not a data frame with one row?` in one of his comment,
while the `Is there a way to ensure I always get back a data frame?` part has been answered by Dan Allan.

Then, as the Pandas' docs cited above says that the pandas' data structures are best seen as **containers** of lower dimensional data, it seemed to me that the understanding of the *why* would be found in the characteristcs of the nature of DataFrame structures.

However, I realized that this cited advice must not be taken as a precise description of the nature of Pandas' data structures.
This advice doesn't mean that a DataFrame is a container of Series.
It expresses that the mental representation of a DataFrame as a container of Series (either rows or columns according the option considered at one moment of a reasoning) is a good way to consider DataFrames, even if it isn't strictly the case in reality. "Good" meaning that this vision enables to use DataFrames with efficiency. That's all.

.

Then what is a DataFrame object ?

The **DataFrame** class produces instances that have a particular structure originated in the **NDFrame** base class, itself derived from the  **PandasContainer** base class that is also a parent class of the **Series** class.
Note that this is correct for Pandas until version 0.12. In the upcoming version 0.13, **Series** will derive also from **NDFrame** class only.

```
# with pandas 0.12

from pandas import Series
print 'Series  :\n',Series
print 'Series.__bases__  :\n',Series.__bases__

from pandas import DataFrame
print '\nDataFrame  :\n',DataFrame
print 'DataFrame.__bases__  :\n',DataFrame.__bases__

print '\n-------------------'

from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame
print '\nNDFrame.__bases__  :\n',NDFrame.__bases__

from pandas.core.generic import PandasContainer
print '\nPandasContainer.__bases__  :\n',PandasContainer.__bases__

from pandas.core.base import PandasObject
print '\nPandasObject.__bases__  :\n',PandasObject.__bases__

from pandas.core.base import StringMixin
print '\nStringMixin.__bases__  :\n',StringMixin.__bases__
```

result

```
Series  :
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Series.__bases__  :
(<class 'pandas.core.generic.PandasContainer'>, <type 'numpy.ndarray'>)

DataFrame  :
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DataFrame.__bases__  :
(<class 'pandas.core.generic.NDFrame'>,)

-------------------

NDFrame.__bases__  :
(<class 'pandas.core.generic.PandasContainer'>,)

PandasContainer.__bases__  :
(<class 'pandas.core.base.PandasObject'>,)

PandasObject.__bases__  :
(<class 'pandas.core.base.StringMixin'>,)

StringMixin.__bases__  :
(<type 'object'>,)
```

So my understanding is now that a DataFrame instance has certain methods that have been crafted in order to control the way data are extracted from rows and columns.

The ways these extracting methods work are described in this page:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing
We find in it the method given by Dan Allan and other methods.

Why these extracting methods have been crafted as they were ?
That's certainly because they have been appraised as the ones giving the better possibilities and ease in data analysis.
It's precisely what is expressed in this sentence:

> The best way to think about the pandas data structures is as flexible
>   containers for lower dimensional data.

The *why* of the extraction of data from a DataFRame instance doesn't lies in its structure, it lies in the *why* of this structure. I guess that the structure and functionning of the Pandas' data structure have been chiseled in order to be as much intellectually intuitive as possible, and that to understand the details, one must read the blog of Wes McKinney.

Comment: FYI, DataFrame is NOT an ndarray sub-class, neither is a Series (starting 0.13, prior to that it was though). These are more dict-like that anything.

Comment: Thank you to inform me. I really appreciate because I am new in the learning of Pandas. But I need more information to understand well. Why is it written in the docs that a Series is a subclass of ndarray ?

Comment: it was before 0.13 (releasing shortly), here are dev docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#series

Comment: OK. Thank you very much. However it doesn't change the basis of my reasoning and understanding, does it ? - In Pandas inferior to 0.13 , DataFrame and other Pandas' objects different from Series: what are they subclass of ?

Comment: @Jeff Thank you. I modified my answer after your information. I would be pleased to know what you think of my edit.

Answer (score 3):

If the objective is to get a subset of the data set using the index, it is best to avoid using `loc` or `iloc`. Instead you should use syntax similar to this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=range(5), index=[1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
result = df[df.index == 3] 
isinstance(result, pd.DataFrame) # True

result = df[df.index == 1]
isinstance(result, pd.DataFrame) # True
```

Comment: The syntax `result = df[df.index == idx] ` is a really nice option; fit my purposes perfectly.

Comment: this then avoids entire performance benefit of having hashmap/indexed index in the first place

Answer (score 3):

every time we put `[['column name']]` it returns Pandas DataFrame object,
if we put `['column name']` we got Pandas Series object

Answer (score 0):

If you also select on the index of the dataframe then the result can be either a DataFrame or a Series **or** it can be a Series or a scalar (single value).

This function ensures that you always get a list from your selection (if the df, index and column are valid):

```
def get_list_from_df_column(df, index, column):
    df_or_series = df.loc[index,[column]] 
    # df.loc[index,column] is also possible and returns a series or a scalar
    if isinstance(df_or_series, pd.Series):
        resulting_list = df_or_series.tolist() #get list from series
    else:
        resulting_list = df_or_series[column].tolist() 
        # use the column key to get a series from the dataframe
    return(resulting_list)
```