# Why is 'series' type not a special case of 'dataframe' type in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Coming from a mathematical and MATLAB background, I am wondering whether there is a technical reason why a series is not equivalent to a 1D dataframe. This would avoid errors in many situations - e.g., where you may want, or expect, your result to be a dataframe but it gets returned as a series.

Comment: I think the last answer for that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383647/pandas-selecting-by-label-sometimes-return-series-sometimes-returns-dataframe kinda explains a bit, there was a refactor in version `0.13.0` where a `DataFrame` and `Series` were no longer subclassing `NDarray` in which case your question would'nt have been relevant. See http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0130-refactoring for more information

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys.