# Best approach to slicing from a (potentially) duplicate index in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

SO Question which triggered my question: [Pandas selecting by label sometimes return series, sometimes returns dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383647/pandas-selecting-by-label-sometimes-return-series-sometimes-returns-dataframe)

I have a dataframe with users, products and clicks. In order to quickly look up which products are clicked by a user I make 'users' the index of the dataframe. I am selecting rows from this df by df.loc[u], but

- If there is only one row => I get a Series
- If there are multiple rows => I get a Dataframe

I always want to have a dataframe. The linked SO question has an accepted answer suggesting to make the lookup as follow: df.loc[[u]], this turns out to be a very bad idea though, as it is much less efficient.

In the  following fragment I compared the runtimes for different access approaches:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np    
from functools import partial
n=1000
s=1000000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(s, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

#modify index to have some duplicates 
l = list(df.index) 
M = s//2
for i in range(10):
    l[M+i] = l[M]
df.index= l

def func1(df):
  return df.loc[20]

def func2(df):
   return df.loc[20:20]

def func3(df):
   return df.loc[df.index == 20]

def func4(df):
   return df.loc[[20]]

print(timeit.timeit( partial(func1, df=df ), number=n )/n)
print(timeit.timeit( partial(func2, df=df ), number=n )/n)
print(timeit.timeit( partial(func3, df=df ), number=n )/n)
print(timeit.timeit( partial(func4, df=df ), number=n )/n)
```

Gives very different runtimes:

```
0.0001941031701862812
0.0001424320638179779
0.0011041645780205727
0.10913500126451253
```

Any insights on why the performance difference is so big? Should I always use the second approach when working with a duplicate index? Or are there cases when another approach is preferred? Avoiding duplicate indexes altogether would probably be the ideal solution but the filter approach (func3) is also quite slow!