# Counting number of rows in a subset of a Pandas dataframe when selecting columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I find how many rows are returned in a subset of a Pandas DataFrame when I'm selecting a column?

In subsetting a Pandas DataFrame and specifying a column, if the subset has more than one row, a Dataframe is returned, but if the subset returns only one row, it returns the value of the subset and I can't get the length of that.

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A1','A2','A1'],'B':['B1','B2','B3']})
>>> df2 = df1.set_index('A')
>>> df3 = df1.iloc[:2,].set_index('A')
>>> df2
     B
A
A1  B1
A2  B2
A1  B3
>>> df3
     B
A
A1  B1
A2  B2
>>> df2.loc['A1','B'].shape
(2,)
>>> df3.loc['A1','B'].shape
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

This is because Pandas returns a pandas object if there is more than one row, and a scalar if it has only one row.

```
>>> df2.loc['A1','B']
A
A1    B1
A1    B3
Name: B, dtype: object
>>> df3.loc['A1','B']
'B1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square brackets to denote a list of indices:

```
print(df3.loc[['A1'], 'B'].shape)
# (1,)
```

This indicates to `pandas` that you want to output a `pd.Series` object.

Answer (score 0):

Ah.. [Pandas selecting by label sometimes return series, sometimes returns dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383647/pandas-selecting-by-label-sometimes-return-series-sometimes-returns-dataframe)

The key is to pass the filter criteria as a list:

```
>>> df3.loc[['A1'],'B'].size
1
```