# TypeError: nlargest() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a python script to return the top 5 rows of a dataframe using the pandas `nlargest()` method. In its documentation seen [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) , it states that it can take `columns` as a keyword argument. However when I'm using it my file, I get an `unexpected keyword argument`. The only explanation that I can think of for this is that when I get the error, columns is assigned to a single-element list containing a column name, but when it does work, columns is assigned to the actual column name. I have attached my code as follows below.

```py
def question_3(df, vehicles):
    #Vehicles is a list of column names, that could contain just one element
    #Drop all entries where the road name is U or C
    df = df[(df['road_name'] != 'U') & (df['road_name'] != 'C')]

    if len(vehicles) > 1:
        joint_names = '_'.join(vehicles)
        df.loc[joint_names] = df[vehicles].sum(axis = 1)
        df = df.drop(columns = vehicles, axis = 1)
       
        df = df.groupby([df.index.year,'road_name', 'count_point_id'])[joint_names].sum().groupby(level = ('road_name')).mean().nlargest(5, columns = joint_names)
    else:
        df = df.groupby([df.index.year,'road_name', 'count_point_id'])[vehicles].sum().groupby(level = ('road_name')).mean().nlargest(5, columns = 'all_motor_vehicles')

#Error here
question_3(scottish_roads.df, ['pedal_cycles', 'buses_and_coaches'])

#No error here
question_3(scottish_roads.df, ['pedal_cycles'])
```

Note that `nlargest()` is being called at the end of the long query.

This issue has happened before but with a different keyword argument. It was posted on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21411) but has now been closed and fixed.

Comment: this is not a [mcve] so it might take a while for someone with the patience/knowledge to help you out

Comment: also, you're not including the trace, and the error might not come from nlargest but from the `drop`, that's my bet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more researching, I have discovered that the function `nlargest()` is different if you're calling it on a series or a dataframe. I have found what has caused this slight discrepancy.

When the `else:` statement is run, the list `vehicles` is passed and put into another list. Seen here:

```py
df.groupby([df.index.year,'road_name', 'count_point_id'])[vehicles].sum()
```

However, when the `if` statement is run, the column name (string) `joint_names` is passed *into* a list, not *as* a list. Seen here:

```py
df.groupby([df.index.year,'road_name', 'count_point_id'])[joint_names].sum()
```

This causes a pandas *series* to be returned, not a *dataframe*. And the Series version of `nlargest()` *does not* have `columns` as a keyword argument.

The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383647/pandas-selecting-by-label-sometimes-return-series-sometimes-returns-dataframe) helped solve this. If anyone else has this same issue, this answer explains the reason why sometimes series and dataframes are returned.