# .loc returns a Pandas Series, not a GeoDataFrame. How to return a GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html) like this

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'City': ['Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Santiago', 'Bogota', 'Caracas'],
     'Country': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Venezuela'],
     'Latitude': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
     'Longitude': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86]})

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))

gdf.set_index("City", inplace = True)
```

Now I want to have a subset of the Data. I do this by

```
gdf.loc["Santiago"]
```

However, this returns a

```
type(gdf.loc["Santiago"])
```

> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

I want a `GeoDataFrame` as a return / Convert `pandas.core.series.Series` into a `GeoDataFrame`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383647/pandas-selecting-by-label-sometimes-return-series-sometimes-returns-dataframe), this will do the trick.

```
gdf.loc[["Santiago"]]
type(gdf.loc[["Santiago"]])
```

> <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>

Answer (score 0):

```
gdf.loc["Santiago"]
```

**output**

```
Country                      Chile
Latitude                    -33.45
Longitude                   -70.66
geometry     POINT (-70.66 -33.45)
Name: Santiago, dtype: object
```

This is a series, *Country, Latitude & Longitude* are not geometry. Hence it has to be a *Series* to represent the row from the *GeoDataFrame*

Locate just the geometry:

```
type(gdf.loc["Santiago", "geometry"])
```

**output**

```
shapely.geometry.point.Point
```

Is an individual geometry (not a *Series* or *GeoSeries*) as expected as it uniquely identifies a value.